# Receiving two callbacks from modal in Native script Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript

I Want to send back two parameters when I close my modal,I can successfully get back ones parameter,   the code below is what i've tried but it doesn't work and i cant find much on this around the internet , appreciate any help thanks.

```
 onHandleInput(action: string, id: number) {
  this.modalParams.closeCallback(action,id);
}

 changePerson(index) {
    //open up modal for choosing an exercise
    this.modalDialog.showModal(PersonListModalComponent, {
     fullscreen: false,
    viewContainerRef: this.uiService.getRootVCRef() ? this.uiService.getRootVCRef() : this.vcRef, context: {}})
    .then(({action,id}) => {this.personName = action,this.personId = id ,this.updatePersonChange(index)});
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide your code in https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: Try calling close callback with an object, `this.modalParams.closeCallback({action,id})`.

Comment: @Manoj, the callback must be `this.modalParams.closeCallback({action:action,id:id})`

Comment: The above one is same, it's a shorter ES6 syntax.